# HTML5 Transition and Transform effect.

Tags: html, css, transform, transition

When I click a button, I wanna do some things listed below using HTML5 and CSS3. But I don't know how can I achieve these things **at the same time**.

When I click a button:

Change element A's CSS3 property `-webkit-transform` to `rotateY(180deg)` in 1 second (using `-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 1s;`)

Change element A's CSS3 property `-webkit-transform` to `scale(0.8)` in 0.5 second (using `-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s;`). Then change element A's CSS3 property `-webkit-transform` back to `scale(1)` in 0.5 second (using `-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s;`).

Are there any solutions about this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use [animation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/) rather than transitions:

```
@-webkit-keyframes myAnimation{
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0.8);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) scale(1);
    }
}


div {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}
div:hover {
    -webkit-animation-name: myAnimation;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) scale(1);
}
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/ZpY3e/).